# How to close a QWidget (subwindow of mdi area) by clicking on a pushbutton

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a mainwindow with a mdi area, that add a Qwidget as subwindow.

When i call this QWidget and try to close it by clicking on close pushbutton, it only hides theQWidget, but if I click on QWidget's "X" button, it close correctly.

I need to close the QWidget too, by clicking by the close pushbutton. Someone can help me with this?

thank you very much!

My code at the moment:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignature
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow,  QWidget
from PyQt4 import QtGui,  QtCore
import sys

from ui.Ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from ui.Ui_widget import Ui_widget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True) # does not make any difference, even if I comment this line
        self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSignature("")
    def on_action_widget_triggered(self):
        w = Widget()
        w.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose) # does not make any difference, even if I comment this line
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(w) 
        w.showMaximized()

class Widget(QWidget, Ui_widget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

    @pyqtSignature("")
    def on_pbClose_clicked(self): # this is the "close" pushbutton. Whe i click it, the QWidget only hide. I need to close it, like if I click on It's "X" button
        self.deleteLater()
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    App = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frm = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with QWorkspace instead QMdiArea

on mainwindow init:

```
self.mdi = QtGui.QWorkspace()
self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
```

on QWidget's call:

```
w = Widget()
self.mdi.addWindow(w)
w.showMaximized()
```

so, to close the QWidget, just: `self.close()`

source: Chapter 9, page 290 of book "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt - The Definitive Guide to PyQt Programming (2008)"

Comment: Do not use `QWorkspace`, it's an obsolete class. Your original script will work correctly if you use `self.parent().close()`. When you add a widget with `addSubWindow`, it automatically makes it a child of a `QMdiSubWindow` (which is what you need to close).